# How do i use *.txt file as input value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons ... when clicked they display some text in a input field. I use some simple javascript to select which text to display, the one defined under the button with `id="blabla1"` or the one under the button with `id="blabla2"`. 
Is it possible to display the text defined in an external `.txt` file?

It is working fine with the text defined as value under the input button:

```
<input type="hidden" id="SupSite1Title" value="Subsite1 Title!"><br>
```

but i want text from a `txt` file instead.

```
<body>  

<div id="leftnav">
<ul>
<li><input type="text" id="TextField1"><br><br></li>
</ul>   
</div>

<div id="rightnav">
<ul>
<li><button id="blabla1" onclick="myFunction1()">Side1</button></li>
<li><button id="blabla2" onclick="myFunction2()">Side2</button></li>
</ul>   
</div>


<input type="hidden" id="SupSite1Title" value="Subsite1 Title!"><br>
<input type="hidden" id="SupSite2Title" value="Subsite2 Title!"><br>


<script>
function myFunction1() {document.getElementById("TextField1").value =document.getElementById("SupSite1Title").value;
}
</script>
<script>
function myFunction2() {document.getElementById("TextField1").value =document.getElementById("SupSite2Title").value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the text content of the `.txt` file ... you can use an API called [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (you need to check if your browser supports that)

here is how you can do it :

**UPDATED :**

```js
var file1 = document.getElementById('file1');
var file2 = document.getElementById('file2');

document.getElementById('bOne').addEventListener("click", function(){getFile(file1)})
document.getElementById('bTwo').addEventListener("click", function(){getFile(file2)})


function getFile(target) {
 const input = target;
  if ('files' in input && input.files.length > 0) {
   placeFileContent(
      document.getElementById('display'),
      input.files[0])
  }
}

function placeFileContent(target, file) {
 readFileContent(file).then(content => {
   target.value = content
  }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

function readFileContent(file) {
 const reader = new FileReader()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onload = event => resolve(event.target.result)
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error)
    reader.readAsText(file)
  })
}
```

```css
label {
display : block;
margin-top : 40px;
margin-bottom : 20px;
}
```

```html
<label for="file1">Upload file 1 : </label>
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="file1"  name="file1">

<label for="file2">Upload file 2 : </label>
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="file2"  name="file2">


<button id="bOne">Display file1</button>
<button id="bTwo">Display file2</button>

<label for="file2">Selected file :  </label>
<input type="text" id="display" for="display">
```

**METHOD N°2** (data fetching from a server) :

```js
function fetchData(buttonNumber) {
  var btn1 = document.getElementById('b1')
  var btn2 = document.getElementById('b2')
  var display = document.getElementById('display')
  //fetching data
  if (buttonNumber == 1) {
    //replace 'file1.txt' with your file URL
    fetch('file1.txt').then(x => {
      x.text().then(function(text) {
        display.value = text
      });
    })
  } else {
    //replace 'file2.txt' with your file URL
    fetch('file2.txt').then(x => {
       x.text().then(function(text) {
        display.value = text
      });
    })
  }
}
```

```css
#b1,
#b2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<button id="b1" onclick="fetchData(1)">Get file 1 and show it</button>
<button id="b2" onclick="fetchData(2)">Get file 2 and show it</button>

<label for="file2">Selected file :  </label>
<input type="text" id="display" for="display">
```

Comment: Hi Dadboz, thanks a lot for your response. My overall goal is to have one textfield and three buttons. If the user pres button1 then the content of "textfile1.txt" soud be shown in in the textfield. If the user pres button2 then the text content of "textfile2.txt" should be displayed in the text field. I am completely new i html/java. Is my solution a good one or would you go for something else?

Comment: @Birch78 it's unclear what you are asking .... please do update your Question explaining the expected results and more details on what are you trying to do ... you need to upload `.txt` files first then it's up to you wherever you want to show them

Comment: sorry for not being very clear. I want to have one text field on my html site. Then I have two *.txt files (file1.txt and file2.txt). Then I want to have two buttons on my html site and if the user select button1 then the content of file1.txt should appear in the text field. If the user then click button 2 the content of file2.txt should appear in the text filed. Only one button should be selected at the time and therefore only one *.txt content visible in the text field at the time. I hope this is more clear

Comment: @Birch78 Thanks for clearing out ... so now you need TWO inputs (with `type="file"` ) to upload the two `.txt` files right ? and another input (with `type="text"`) to display the text of the selected file `.txt` ( so in total you need 3 inputs ) ... and also we need 2 buttons to select which file we want to display (file1.txt or file2.txt) right? if yes ....then i will update my answer with the previous changes

Comment: @Birch78 i updated the answer you can run it now again

Comment: Hi Dadboz, that is almost perfect. Thanks a lot for helping me. The only thing is that file1 and file2 should not be uploaded by the user. I will upload the two files on the server. The buttons simply select which of them are displayed.

Comment: As a final thing could you show me how I should hardcode file1.txt to button1 and file2.txt to button2? THANKS A LOT for all your help

Comment: @Birch78 no problem , what do you mean exactly by "hardcode" a file into a button element :)

Comment: @Birch78 you mean like... you don't need inputs for the files just two buttons will do everything and just a single input field to display the text ?

Comment: Yes just two buttons that do everything. So what I need is just the two display buttons from your Code snippet example and the "selected file" field. So it I click "Display file 1" the content of file1.txt is displayed and if I click "Display file 2" then the content of file1.txt is displayed. The two *.txt files are uploaded to the server.

Comment: @Birch78 cool , i updated the answer with another method N°2(server fetching)

Comment: Thank your very VERY much Dadboz. I believe the codes is working fine. I do however get a "[object Promise]" in the text field, but I will try to find out what the problem is.

Comment: @Birch78 your welcome , concerning "[object Promise]" ..try this `x.text().then(function (x) {
  display.value = x;
});` instead .. i didn't try the code so .. i will update it again

Comment: @Birch78 yes if everything is secured and nothing to worry about please do update your question using them

Comment: EVERYTHING is working PERFECTLY, thanks a lot for all you help. If I ever meet you I buy you a beer.

Comment: @Birch78 haha thanks bro , wish you the best on your career

Answer (score 0):

Give the input field the attributes `type="file"` and `accept=".txt"`, and that should work

```
<input type="file" accept=".txt" />
```

And you can read this `.txt` file using node.js(Also you can read it with vanilla js), But i prefer node.js like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileData = fs.readFileSync('fileName.txt', 'utf-8');
console.log(fileData) // Whatever inside .txt file
```

**Update according to comment:**

Suppose in your project folder, you have one `index.html` file and one `index.js` file. Create two `.txt` file named as `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` And write something on those file. NOTE: For simplicity i am writing solution using `jQuery`.

***index.html***

```
<body>
    <p id="text-field"></p>
    <button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
</body>
```

***index.js***

```
const fs = require('fs');
let fileData = '';

$('#btn1').click(()=> {
    fileData = fs.readFileSync('file1.txt', 'utf-8');
    $('#text-field').append(fileData);
});

$('#btn2').click(()=> {
    fileData = fs.readFileSync('file2.txt', 'utf-8');
    $('#text-field').append(fileData);
});
```

That's it. According to button click text will be append into `p` element.

You can handle two button click with one function also, like this

```
$('button').click(event => {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if($(event.target).attr('id') === 'btn1') {
        fileData = fs.readFileSync('file1.txt', 'utf-8');
        $('#text-field').append(fileData);
    }else if($(event.target).attr('id') === 'btn2') {
        fileData = fs.readFileSync('file2.txt', 'utf-8');
        $('#text-field').append(fileData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks a lot for your response. i hope you are ready for a new question. My overall goal is to have one textfield and three buttons. If the user pres button1 then the content of "textfile1.txt" soud be shown in in the textfield. If the user pres button2 then the text content of "textfile2.txt" should be displayed in the text field. I am completely new i html/java. Is my solution a good one or would you go for something else?

Comment: According your comment, you need to define two separate button click event listener - one for button1 and another for button2. And you need push your textfile1.txt and textfile2.txt into database or server. Then you can read it according to button click.
Otherwise no need any `input` field. Just write two `.txt` file in your project folder and read it according to button click.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so st...., but could you show me how this could be implemented in the my code above? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @Birch78 see updated answer please. If you find this your expected answer, please mark it as `Accept` and `Upvote` :) ---Happy Coding---

Comment: I will accept and upvote immediately. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the contents of a text file you cannot load it from local file system. You should put it on server and load it from there.